# Convert torrent files from hybrid format to v1 format

Tags: transmission

I'm attempting to convert existing torrent files from hybrid format to v1 format, because transmission seemly has issues parsing torrent files in hybrid format.

Basically, I remove the "file tree" slot from the torrent file with simple scripts.

A "working" example:

```python
import torrent_parser
data = torrent_parser.parse_torrent_file('hybrid.torrent')
data['info'].pop('file tree')
torrent_parser.create_torrent_file('v1.torrent', data)
```

Where `torrent_parser` is a python module that you can find with `pip`.

However, when I pass the created torrent file to transmission I get the "The requested torrent does not exist on this tracker." error, so it doesn't really work.

Is it because the info hash is incorrect since I change the content? Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the info hash will change whenever you make any changes to `data['info']`. (That's why it's *called* the "info hash".) The only workaround here is to fix Transmission – which seems to [have already been done](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/commit/fb39c4663c9e6b7fadc7cd55bdcfa04167ae53f1) post-3.0.

Comment: Good to know at least it is fixed in the code but sad to know they haven't officially released it yet after fixing it for half an year already...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nice little utility, called
[Torrent File Editor](https://torrent-file-editor.github.io/)
to generate magnet links from `.torrent` files, or for other editing.

This saves you the trouble of using a torrent client app for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Such application does make things easier. However, I don't see how it changes the situation as @user1686 suggested. Moreover, in my test, I can't even remove the ```tree``` slot with this application, probably because the devs know the torrent file would corrupt as well...